# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 34: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, encoding

I wanna open some text file in Persian language in python file with bellow code:

```
 for line in codecs.open('0001.txt',encoding='UTF-8'):
       lines.appends(line)
```

but it gives me this error :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/nlpuser/Documents/ms/Work/General_Dataset_creator/BijanKhanReader.py", line 24, in <module>
    for lin in codecs.open('corpuses/markaz/0001.txt',encoding='UTF-8'):
  File "/home/nlpuser/anaconda3/envs/tmpy36/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 713, in __next__
    return next(self.reader)
  File "/home/nlpuser/anaconda3/envs/tmpy36/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 644, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
  File "/home/nlpuser/anaconda3/envs/tmpy36/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 557, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "/home/nlpuser/anaconda3/envs/tmpy36/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 503, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

what is wrong with this code ?

and his is the output for file :

> 0001.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 has a very specific format, given that a character can be represented by anywhere from one to four bytes.

If a character is **single-byte**, it will be represented by `0x00-0x7F`. If it is represented by **two** or more, the *leading* byte will start with `0xC2 to 0xF4`, followed by one to three *continuation* bytes, in range of `0x80 to 0xBF`.

In your case, Python found a character that is in the position of a continuation character (i.e. one of the characters following the lead character), but is `0xE3`, which is not a legal continuation character. The problem is likely in your text file, not in your program - either bad encoding, or wrong encoding.

Use `hexdump -C <file>` or `xxd <file>` to verify what exact sequence of bytes you have and `file <file>` to try to guess the encoding, and we might be able to say more.

Comment: this is the output for file : 0001.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: ... in other words, not UTF-8.

Comment: @ Amadan  so what is it?

Comment: How would I know? You haven’t posted the file. All I can tell you it’s not utf-8.

Comment: I (and Google Chrome) believe it is [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256). `puts File.read("0002.txt", encoding: Encoding::CP1256).encode(Encoding::UTF_8)` should give you something useful.